Insert ID post instead of name post in slug (permalink) wordpress
I have a custom post type that I want the post ID to be written in the slug instead of the post name when it is published. I type the following code and it works, but the problem is that after the ID, it also leaves -2, and apparently it shows that this ID is duplicated, while this has happened many times and none of these IDs are duplicated.
My custom post name is e
add_action( 'save_post_e', 'wpse251743_set_title', 10, 3 );
function wpse251743_set_title ( $post_id ){
    //This temporarily removes action to prevent infinite loops
    remove_action( 'save_post_e', 'wpse251743_set_title' );
    //update title
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID'        => $post_id,
        'post_name' =>  $post_id, //Wordpress would generate the slug based on the post name
    ));
    //redo action
    add_action( 'save_post_e', 'wpse251743_set_title', 10, 3 );
}

I want that -2 to be deleted. If I need to write the code from the beginning, I would be grateful if you could fix the problem for me
Thanks
